# php concatenating string with dynamic variable

Tags: php

I'm not getting full text while concatenation the string with dynamic variable from database. My code is:

`$page ="<input type='text' name='neil' value=".$blogname.">";`

I'm getting output like this:

`<input type="text" name="neil" value="My" test's="">`

Expected output:

```
<input type="text" name="neil" value="My test's">
```

Comment: You're not putting any quotes to output for your value.

Comment: So what does `$blogname` contain?

Comment: `name'neil'` certainly will not be magically changed to `name='neil'` by the php fairies.

Comment: Actually I seriously doubt you _really_ get what you claim you get. Makes no sense. It _might_ be that some browser engine cuts in to try to fix your invalid html markup. But what you post is _not_ what php outputs.

Comment: @Neil Dhakal consider approving the answer that helped you out, so that it helps the community.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to go about it is:

```
$page ='<input type="text" name="neil" value="'.$blogname.'">';
```

You need to enclose the value of the html element within quotes `" "`

Answer (score 0):

Enclose value in single quotes, and add a = after name. Put a / before > if you really want to too:

```
$page ="<input type='text' name='neil' value='".$blogname."'/>";
```

Comment: $blogname contains single string. like $blogname = it's mine

Comment: / is not really necessary in an input tag according to the HTML5 standards .

Comment: @NeilDhakal - actually I missed that $blogname contained a  single quote, so Shakti's answer is better

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal - hence "if you really want to", but yes - you're right.

Comment: @markdwhite the OP does not need a useless suggestion. No issues otherwise.

Comment: This is my code: $blogname ="<input id='first-name' required='required' class='form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12' name='postName' type='text' value='".$blogtitle."'/>"

and my variable contains single quote like : it's 

I'm getting output like : it only.

Comment: @NeilDhakal - see the answer currently receiving upvotes

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your value for your HTML. The nice thing about double quotes is that you don't need to break out of them to add in your variable, and you're able to notice the missing quotes easier. So your string can look like this:

```
$page ="<input type='text' name='neil' value='$blogname'>";
```

Or

```
$page ="<input type='text' name='neil' value='{$blogname}'>";
```

The second one is great for when you're using array values, like so:

```
$page ="<input type='text' name='neil' value='{$row['blogname']}'>";
```